# How to emulate pike of Starbucks

Tags: coffee, restaurant-mimicry

Recently, I have developed a taste for pike roast flavor of Starbucks. I was wondering if I can make coffee with the same taste in my home? What would be the coffee bean and an appropriate coffee maker for that?

Comment: Definitely belongs to Cooking SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest answer is: buy the Pike coffee blend from Starbucks, they sell their beans.

Brew it at home with any method you prefer.  The coffee maker you use is a matter of preference.  Starbucks themselves use a large drip pot, which is the most common home type.

If you want to avoid using Starbucks beans, from the description of the roast (I haven't tasted it in quite a while, and it didn't make an impression), it sounds like a mountain grown coffee, something like Kenyan would be a good choice.  Since they describe it as low acidity, I am guessing that it might be somewhat less over-roasted than Starbucks coffee usually is, so I would suggest a Full City Roast, or perhaps a Vienna roast.

Its certainly a blend, so no single bean will replicate it.  I would suggest finding a blend from a reputable coffee roaster that you like, or simply buying the Pike blend from Starbucks.